# DirectShow (C#), Preview FPS and CPU usage are dropping with time

Tags: c#, webcam, directshow, frame-rate, directshow.net

I am building a winforms application to learn DirectShow. I got everything working fine, except a strange issue with CPU usage and FPS dropping over the time. 
The PC in use is low spec. So, I get 40% CPU usage at the beginning, which is great. Then within 30 mins or so, it goes as low as 4%. Surely, the FPS also drops to a few FPS.

I have run and tried other sample apps from internet and they are all acting in a roughly similar way. They all use DirectShowLib too. So the basis is the same as my app.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using DirectShowLib;
namespace WebCamPerfTestProject
{
public partial class Cftp_Form1 : Form
{        
    public enum PlayState : int
    {
        Stopped,
        Paused,
        Running,
        Init
    }
    private PlayState CurrentState = PlayState.Stopped;
    private int WM_GRAPHNOTIFY = Convert.ToInt32("0X8000", 16) + 1;
    private IVideoWindow videoWindow = null;        
    private IMediaControl mediaControl = null;
    private IMediaEventEx mediaEventEx = null;
    private IGraphBuilder graph = null;
    private ICaptureGraphBuilder2 pGraphBuilder = null;
    private IBaseFilter pUSB = null;
    private IAMStreamConfig streamConfig = null;        
    private VideoInfoHeader format = null;
    private AMMediaType pmt = null;
    private decimal ratio = Decimal.Divide(1280, 720); //temp values
    private decimal height;
    public Cftp_Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Resize += new EventHandler(WebCamControl_Resize);
        Console.WriteLine("Building graph...");
        GetInterfaces();

        Console.WriteLine("Start capture...");
        CaptureVideo(graph);
        }
    private void GetInterfaces()
    {
        graph = (IGraphBuilder)(new FilterGraph());
        pGraphBuilder = (ICaptureGraphBuilder2)(new CaptureGraphBuilder2());
        mediaControl = (IMediaControl)graph;
        videoWindow = (IVideoWindow)graph;
        mediaEventEx = (IMediaEventEx)graph;
        // send notification messages to the control window
        int hr = mediaEventEx.SetNotifyWindow(Handle, WM_GRAPHNOTIFY, IntPtr.Zero);
        DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
    }
    private void CaptureVideo(IGraphBuilder pGraph)
    {
        int hr = 0;
        hr = pGraphBuilder.SetFiltergraph(pGraph);
            DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

        pUSB = FindCaptureDevice();

        hr = pGraph.AddFilter(pUSB, "WebCamControl Video");
        DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);


        //add smartTee
        IBaseFilter pSmartTee = (IBaseFilter)new SmartTee();
        hr = pGraph.AddFilter(pSmartTee, "Smart Tee");
        DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

        //connect smart tee to camera 
        hr = pGraphBuilder.RenderStream(null, MediaType.Video, pUSB, null, pSmartTee);
        DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);


        pmt = new AMMediaType();
        pmt.majorType = MediaType.Video;
        pmt.subType = MediaSubType.MJPG;
        pmt.formatType = FormatType.VideoInfo;
        pmt.fixedSizeSamples = false; //true for 640x480
        pmt.formatSize = 88;
        pmt.sampleSize = 2764800; //2764800 614400
        pmt.temporalCompression = false;
        //////////////////////////////////
        format = new VideoInfoHeader();
        format.SrcRect = new DsRect();
        format.TargetRect = new DsRect();
        format.BitRate = 5000000;
        format.AvgTimePerFrame = 666666;
        //////////////////////////////////            
        format.BmiHeader = new BitmapInfoHeader();
        format.BmiHeader.Size = 40;
        format.BmiHeader.Width = 1280;
        format.BmiHeader.Height = 720;
        format.BmiHeader.Planes = 1;
        format.BmiHeader.BitCount = 24;
        format.BmiHeader.Compression = 1196444237; //1196444237 //844715353
        format.BmiHeader.ImageSize = 2764800; //2764800 614400
        pmt.formatPtr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(format));
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(format, pmt.formatPtr, false);
        Debug.WriteLine(getCatName(pUSB) + " at line 130");
        streamConfig = (IAMStreamConfig)GetPin(pUSB, getCatName(pUSB));
        hr = streamConfig.SetFormat(pmt);
        DsUtils.FreeAMMediaType(pmt);
        if (hr < 0)
        {
            CapTest.CustomMessage.ShowMessage("Can`t set format");
            DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
        }
        //add MJPEG Decompressor
        IBaseFilter pMJPEGDecompressor = (IBaseFilter)new MjpegDec();
        hr = pGraph.AddFilter(pMJPEGDecompressor, "MJPEG Decompressor");
        if (hr < 0)
        {
            CapTest.CustomMessage.ShowMessage("Can`t add MJPEG Decompressor");
            DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
        }

        //add SampleGrabber
        IBaseFilter pSampleGrabber = (IBaseFilter)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(CLSID_SampleGrabber));
        hr = pGraph.AddFilter(pSampleGrabber, "SampleGrabber");
        checkHR(hr, "Can't add SampleGrabber to graph");

        //connect Smart Tee and SampleGrabber
        hr = pGraph.ConnectDirect(GetPin(pSmartTee, "Preview"), GetPin(pSampleGrabber, "Input"), null);            
        checkHR(hr, "Can't connect Smart Tee and SampleGrabber");

        //connect smart tee to camera 
        hr = pGraphBuilder.RenderStream(null, MediaType.Video, pSampleGrabber, null, pMJPEGDecompressor);

        //add Color Space Converter 
        IBaseFilter pColorSpaceConverter = (IBaseFilter)new Colour();
        hr = pGraph.AddFilter(pColorSpaceConverter, "Color Space Converter");
        if (hr < 0)
        {
            CapTest.CustomMessage.ShowMessage("Can't add Color Space Converter to graph");
            DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
        }
        hr = pGraphBuilder.RenderStream(null, MediaType.Video, pMJPEGDecompressor, null, pColorSpaceConverter);
        DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

        IBaseFilter videoRender = (IBaseFilter)new VideoRenderer();
        hr = pGraph.AddFilter(videoRender, "Video Render");
        DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

        hr = pGraphBuilder.RenderStream(null, MediaType.Video, pColorSpaceConverter, null, videoRender);
        DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
        Debug.WriteLine(DsError.GetErrorText(hr) + " is error in rendering");





        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pUSB);

        SetupVideoWindow();



    }

    //Access the camera
    private IBaseFilter FindCaptureDevice()
    {
        IEnumMoniker classEnum = null;
        IMoniker[] moniker = new IMoniker[1];
        object source = null;
        ICreateDevEnum devEnum = (ICreateDevEnum)(new CreateDevEnum());
        int hr = devEnum.CreateClassEnumerator(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice, out classEnum, CDef.None);
        DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(devEnum);
        if (classEnum == null)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("No video capture device was detected.\\r\\n\\r\\n" + "This sample requires a video capture device, such as a USB WebCam,\\r\\nto be installed and working properly.  The sample will now close.");
        }
        IntPtr none = IntPtr.Zero;
        if (classEnum.Next(moniker.Length, moniker, none) == 0)
        {
            Guid iid = typeof(IBaseFilter).GUID;
            moniker[0].BindToObject(null, null, ref iid, out source);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Unable to access video capture device!");
        }
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(moniker[0]);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(classEnum);
        return (IBaseFilter)source;
    }

    static IPin GetPin(IBaseFilter filter, string pinname)
    {
        IEnumPins epins;
        int hr = filter.EnumPins(out epins);
        if (hr < 0)
        {
            CapTest.CustomMessage.ShowMessage("Cant enumerate pins");
            DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
        }

        IntPtr fetched = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(4);
        IPin[] pins = new IPin[1];
        while (epins.Next(1, pins, fetched) == 0)
        {
            PinInfo pinfo;
            pins[0].QueryPinInfo(out pinfo);
            bool found = (pinfo.name == "Capture");
            CapTest.CustomMessage.ShowMessage(pinfo.name + " is PIN NAME");
            DsUtils.FreePinInfo(pinfo);
            if (found)
                return pins[0];
        }

        CapTest.CustomMessage.ShowMessage("Pin not found");
        DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

        return null;
    }

    string getCatName(IBaseFilter filter)
    {
        string retval = "";
        IEnumPins epins;
        int hr = filter.EnumPins(out epins);
        if (hr < 0)
        {
            CapTest.CustomMessage.ShowMessage("Cant enumerate pins");
            DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
        }

        IntPtr fetched = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(4);
        IPin[] pins = new IPin[1];
        while (epins.Next(1, pins, fetched) == 0)
        {
            PinInfo pinfo;
            pins[0].QueryPinInfo(out pinfo);
            bool found = (pinfo.name == "Capture");
            CapTest.CustomMessage.ShowMessage(pinfo.name + " is pinname on getCatName");
            DsUtils.FreePinInfo(pinfo);
            if (found)
                retval = pinfo.name;
        }
        CapTest.CustomMessage.ShowMessage("Pin found " + retval);
        return retval;
    }
    private void SetupVideoWindow()
    {
        int hr = 0;

        //set the video window to be a child of the main window
        //putowner : Sets the owning parent window for the video playback window. 
        hr = videoWindow.put_Owner(pictureBox1.Handle);
        DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);


        hr = videoWindow.put_WindowStyle(WindowStyle.Child | WindowStyle.ClipChildren);
        DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

        //Use helper function to position video window in client rect of main application window
        WebCamControl_Resize(this, null);

        //Make the video window visible, now that it is properly positioned
        //put_visible : This method changes the visibility of the video window. 
        hr = videoWindow.put_Visible(OABool.True);
        DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

        hr = mediaControl.Run();
        DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
        HandleGraphEvent();
        CurrentState = PlayState.Running;

        Cftp_Form1.ActiveForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    }


    private void HandleGraphEvent()
    {
        int hr = 0;
        EventCode evCode = 0;
        IntPtr evParam1 = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr evParam2 = IntPtr.Zero;

        while (mediaEventEx != null && mediaEventEx.GetEvent(out evCode, out evParam1, out evParam2, 0) == 0)
        {
            // Free event parameters to prevent memory leaks associated with
            // event parameter data.  While this application is not interested
            // in the received events, applications should always process them.
            hr = mediaEventEx.FreeEventParams(evCode, evParam1, evParam2);
            DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

            Console.WriteLine(evCode + " " + evParam1 + " " + evParam2);
            // Insert event processing code here, if desired (see http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms783649.aspx)
        }
    }

    private void ReleaseInterfaces()
    {
        if (mediaControl != null)
            mediaControl.StopWhenReady();

        CurrentState = PlayState.Stopped;

        // stop notifications of events
        if (mediaEventEx != null)
            mediaEventEx.SetNotifyWindow(IntPtr.Zero, WM_GRAPHNOTIFY, IntPtr.Zero);

        //// below we relinquish ownership (IMPORTANT!) of the video window.
        //// Failing to call put_Owner can lead to assert failures within
        //// the video renderer, as it still assumes that it has a valid
        //// parent window.
        if (videoWindow != null)
        {
            videoWindow.put_Visible(OABool.False);
            videoWindow.put_Owner(IntPtr.Zero);
        }

        // Release DirectShow interfaces
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mediaControl);
        mediaControl = null;

        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mediaEventEx);
        mediaEventEx = null;

        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(videoWindow);
        videoWindow = null;

        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(graph);
        graph = null;

        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pGraphBuilder);
        pGraphBuilder = null;
    }


    private void WebCamControl_Resize(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        //Resize the video preview window to match owner window size
        //Calculate the ratio like 16/9
        // 1280/720=1.77777778
        if (videoWindow != null)
            height = Convert.ToDecimal(pictureBox1.Width) / ratio;
        int iheight = (int)height;
        videoWindow.SetWindowPosition(0, 0, pictureBox1.Width, iheight);
        //Debug.WriteLine(pictureBox1.Width +" "+ iheight + " ratio:" + ratio);

        mediaControl.Run();

    }
    private void Cftp_Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        ReleaseInterfaces();
    }
}
}
```

Is there a way I could keep the process "alive"? 
Maybe by requesting for frames at certain intervals?

If that is even possible, how can I "request" for more frames?

Comment: DirectShow was deprecated 13 years ago, replaced by Media Foundation.  Old Microsoft libraries never die, but in particular DS aged very poorly.  Don't do it is the only decent advise.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I googled and found some stuff on MF. 
I am kinda back at square one, only this time with MF. It is OK as long as I can get to build something worthy, quickly.
I spent 2 weeks leaning DirectShow and got it working and learnt some things about COM. which seem to be useful with MF as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first comment here is to learn how to visualize your DirectShow filter graph and understand what is effectively built. Whether you are developing in C++ or in C# through .NET interface library, you quite so often build by adding parts of the pipeline explicitly and then something is added for you. You don't know what you end up with exactly, so you need to…

… [Understand Your DirectShow Filter Graph](http://alax.info/blog/1678)

That is, have your application build the pipeline and then inspect it with developer's tooling. This also helps sharing information when you ask a question like this.

In your case your graph building is not good: you first create a Null Renderer yourself, and then you request `IVideoWindow` and implicitly connect to Video Renderer supplied for you automatically. This means that you don't understand the pipeline and your question and problem is coming partially from this misunderstanding.

Next thing is that you are connecting live video source to synchronous renderer, which is - generally speaking - designed to display video with pre-buffered frames ahead of time. My guess here is that frame times slide away so that video renderer is blocking streaming and incrementally increases wait time causing more waiting and less capturing. I will skip details why it happens this way exactly, however important to know is that you are interested in inserting a [Smart Tee Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/smart-tee-filter) downstream to camera and upstream to renderer, connecting preview output to visual presentation. MSDN documentation gives some details on why this is expected to be done and the purpose.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You did point out vital issues and I did my best to fix them. 
I have changed the CaptureVideo() content.
I am still getting the same issue. It seems to be related to the **picturebox**.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The solution was to add a *SampleGrabber* on the *Preview* pin of the *Smart Tee*. For the reasons you did not mention, and I still don't know, there was issue with feeding *Capture* data to the preview. Proper *Preview* pin was required and *SampleGrabber* did the trick.